# Laravel Eloquent Relationship foreign key with condition?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship, relation

I'm building a forum with threads and comments. Both threads and comments can be reported. So I have 3 models: Thread, Comment and Report.

The report table should be used for both threads and comments for users to report spam and harassment. It has the following columns:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('reported_type');
$table->unsignedInteger('reported_id');
```

reported_type can either be 'thread' or 'comment' and the reported_id is the id of the corresponding thread.

Now I am struggling to form proper relationships with eloquent. Because within the 'thread' model I cannot just say

```
public function reports()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Report::class, 'reported_id');
}
```

because it's not clear whether the id belongs to a comment or a thread.

What could be a solution to this? I would really like to use one report table only to keep it simple.

Thanks!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 3):

You can add additional conditions in your eloquent relationship, example:

```
public function reports()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Report::class, 'reported_id')->where('reported_type', 'thread');
}
```

same go to another Model

Comment: wow, this is what I would have guessed.. Laravel is way too easy. But I didn't find it in the documentation. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define polymorphic relation for such case
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations